# EmberJS Custom Textbox View with ID-suffix

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Let's assume I've got this Ember.ArrayController:

```
App.ItemsArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    //some additional functions
}).create()
```

This array controller holds objects of:

```
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({
   id: 0, //after item is loaded this id contains real id of item
   value: "some value"
})
```

In handlebars template I've got:

```
{{#each item in App.ItemsArrayController}}
   <input id="item" valueBinding="item.value" />
{{/each}}
```

You can see, that input is generated x-times depending on number of items in controller. The issue with this is that all those inputs have same ID of "item". I cannot use something like:

```
<input id="item-{{item.id}}" valueBinding="item.value" />
```

because handle {{ }} wraps value into ember metamorph script wrapper and handle  {{{ }}} works the same way.

What I want to do is custom view which I can use like:

```
{{view App.TextFieldWithIdSuffix id="item-" idSuffixBinding="item.id" valueBinding="item.value"}}
```

and it should be rendered as:

```
<input type="text" id="item-0" value="some text" />
```

My view App.TextFieldWithIdSuffix is defined as:

```
App.TextFieldWithIdSuffix = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName: "input"
});
```

How to define App.TextFieldWithIdSuffix view to support xxxBindings attributes and when rendered the id is altered with suffix?

Comment: Have you considered/tried writing a function either on the controller or as a custom handlebar helper which will convert your id into the desired syntax?  You could then have your input defined as:  `<input id={{functionName item.id}} valueBinding"item.value" />`

Comment: @gravityplanx That looks interesting. Can you point me to some website or provide example of such function?

Comment: I'll provide an answer with the code I would use for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution: Computing of textbox ID is moved to Item model.

Handlebars:

```
<input {{bind-attr id="item.textboxId"}} 
       type="text" {{bind-attr value="item.value"}} />
```

Ember model:

```
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({
   id: 0, //after item is loaded this id contains real id of item
   value: "some value",
   textboxId: function () {
       return "item-" + this.get("id");
   }.property("id")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

On your controller, simply add:

```
idFormat: function(id) {
    return "item-" + id;
}
```

And then write your input tags as:

```
<input id={{idFormat item.id}} valueBinding"item.value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bind-attr helper

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/

Handlebars

`<input type="text" {{bind-attr id="idFormat" }} value="some text" />`

Controller

`idFormat: function(id) {
    return "item-" + id;
}`

Oh, also while the above solves your immediate problem you might want to use the input helpers depending on what you are doing.

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/

Comment: How does the controller function get id parameter?

Comment: Usually it would come from the model which would be setup in the ControllerNameRouter class. My example above is slightly incomplete - I'd probably use property("id") to monitor it rather than pass it in, as in your solution - I'd just do it in the controller not in the model.